# isLoading boolean in react server component

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have this react component, which I want to make a server component by extracting the debounce to another client component. but my question is regarding the isLoading boolean. the boolean right now renders a skeleton in the table cells when isLoading = true. what can I do to make it work if I make page.tsx a server component? the loading.tsx does not work for the table itself if I get it right, it works for the whole page.

page.tsx:

```
"use client";
import useSWR from "swr";

import { columns } from "./columns";
import DataTable from "./data-table";
import useDebounce from "@/shared/hooks/useDebounce";
import { getQueryParams } from "./tableQueryParams";

const TablePage= () => {
  const { name, page, limit, gender } = getQueryParams();
  const debouncedName = useDebounce(name, 500);
  let url = `/${BASE_URL}/?page=${page}&limit=${limit}`;
  if (debouncedName?.length > 0) url += `&name=${debouncedName}`;
  if (gender?.length > 0) url += `&gender=${gender}`;

  const fetcher = async (url: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  };

  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(url, fetcher);

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto py-10">
      <DataTable
        columns={columns}
        data={data}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        error={error}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TablePage;
```

and then I have the datatable:

```
const DataTable = <TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
  isLoading,
  error,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) => {
  const [sorting, setSorting] = useState<SortingState>([]);
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState<ColumnFiltersState>([]);
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState<VisibilityState>({});
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState({});
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState<{ [key: string]: boolean }>({});
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const { name, limit } = getQueryParams();
  const { createQueryString } = useQueryString();

  const tableData = useMemo(
    () => (isLoading ? Array(5).fill({}) : data),
    [isLoading, data]
  );

  const tableColumns = useMemo(
    () =>
      isLoading
        ? (columns as ColumnDef<User>[]).map((column) => ({
            ...column,
            cell: <TableSkeleton />,
          }))
        : columns,
    [isLoading, columns]
  );

  const table = useReactTable({
    columns: tableColumns,
    data: tableData,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
    onSortingChange: setSorting,
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    state: { sorting, columnFilters, columnVisibility, rowSelection },
  });
```